# How can I always return Null for a column without updating the column's value in the database?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
ID      Name         tuition       num of courses
1       Brandon      4430           6  
2       Lisa         2300           3
3       Victoria     null           0
4       Jack         3330           4
```

The type of the tuition column is `money`, but I need to return return `null` in my select statement without updating the values in the table.

I tried `nullif(tuition is not null)`, but it didn't work.

How can I return results like those in the table below, without updating the table or modifying the data in database?

```
ID      Name         tuition       num of courses
1       Brandon      null           6  
2       Lisa         null           3
3       Victoria     null           0
4       Jack         null           4
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to tag this question with the type of database server you are working with

Comment: Yes. I tagged it as tsql

Comment: You ought to tag it with the database software and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Answers often differ between both software products, e.g. MySQL or Oracle, and versions, e.g. SQL Server 2005 introduced Common Table Expressions.

Answer (score 2):

If you are returning null for every row, just code the column as:

```
NULL AS Tuition
```

Example query:

```
SELECT Id, Name, NULL as Tuition, NumCourses FROM TheTable
```

Comment: select null as tuition ? could you please give me an example on how to code it?

Comment: is it possible to set it as an blank space instead of null for tuition field?

Comment: I think I figured it out... isnull(null, '') as tuition; thank you

Comment: @baciyan No need to have `isnull(null, '')`. Instead, just use `'' AS Tuition`.

Comment: I have to null the value first then set it blank. thank you alexander

Comment: @baciyan That doesn't make any sense. The call to `isnull(null, '')` doesn't set anything and will **always** evaluate to true, so it's unnecessary. You can simply return the empty string instead, keeping your code simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I have created the table and inserted records as you have shown above
It is a self join query.

-- To make sure that the underlying table is not updated run both  the queries together.

```
select TT.Id, TT.Name, 
nullif(TT.Tuition, BT.Tuition) as Tuition, TT.NOCs
from tblTuition TT
join tblTuition BT
on TT.Id = Bt.Id


select * from tblTuition
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to get value as null then you can use like this,

```
SELECT NULL AS ABC FROM MYTABLE
```

So above statement add one **ABC** column in your select list AS All `NULL` Values, same thing can be use as getting a Default value e.g. if you want to get 1 then simply use `SELECT 1 AS ABC FROM MYTABLE`